# Is there a way to link apps in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

At the moment I am creating an app to simulate simple mechanical motion in UWP. Instead of creating them all in one blank app I have created multiple different apps for the different types of simulation, eg: single particle, connected particles, pulleys etc... I was wondering if there was a way in which I could have a menu and then when a specific button is clicked the app associated with that button is opened, for example:

```
    private void OpenSingleParticle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //open single particle app
    }
```

Thanks for any help that you can offer

Matt

Comment: Hi, why not use multiple windows instead of multiple apps? It seems a bit weird to seperate them into completely different apps :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# uwp launch apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979131/c-sharp-uwp-launch-apps)

Comment: There is no conceivable reason to split what is to be perceived as a single app into several distinct apps, and then try to backpaddle to uphold that illusion. Just don't break your app, and you won't have to look for complex solutions to then fix it. Write a single app with multiple views.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register app to handle custom URI, then you can call this app using launch app from uri. Take a look at msdn articles:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-app-with-uri

Moreover you can even launch other apps for result as it's possible in Android.